# java jre jdk setup using android bundled jre

Tags: java, android, installation

There are many similar questions but mine is different so please read an entire question before nailing down the new.

Bundled JAVA jdk is automatically installed with Android Studio version 4.0.1. Everything I type java -version on my CMD then I get following message

```
C:\Users\OceanicBlue>java -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

This is because JAVA_HOME is not setup so I tried following inside Environment Variables->System Variables in Windows 10 Machine but no luck. The problem is persistent.

```
JAVA_HOME ->  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\
JAVA_HOME ->  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
JAVA_HOME ->  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
JAVA_HOME ->  %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Can I use Android's bundled JDK for JAVA_HOME? If not then which version should I download. Oracle forces you to register to use their JDK11. I refuse to give them my personal information to use something free. Also I don't want unnecessary extra versions of JAVA installed on my machine. Eventually they will cause problems.

What exactly am I trying to do? I am trying to compile Java programs using Command line. Android installed JDK for me so why not use it? No I am not able to compile a java project using the terminal screen inside Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

> This is because JAVA_HOME is not setup

That's not what's happening. JAVA_HOME is not voodoo magic, the windows shell does not have some sort of built in knowledge. Commands entered are executed by scanning every entry in the PATH environment variable for `java.exe`, `java.com`, or `java.bat`. None are available. If you really want the java.exe found in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin` to be used when you type 'java' on the command line (which will not magically make `javac` work at all, which is why I doubt this is actually want), then add that directory to the PATH variable. JAVA_HOME is mostly useless; a select few dated tools look at it sometimes and fail if it is not there; more modern tools may still look at it but also scan other places, such as the path or windows registry.

Furthermore, that's.. clearly not a bundled JDK, that's a bundled JRE, which can't be used for compiling. It does hava java.exe, but you can't use that to compile things. By nature of being a JRE, it is also obsolete/outdated (JREs are no longer part of how java is distributed; java8 is the last version with a JRE).

Note that `javac` in general is relatively useless when dealing with android; android does not run class files.

Comment: No nothing works magically. About, JRE I was thinking the same but I wasn't sure thanks for making it clear for me. You are saying that I can not use Android studio's  bundled JAVA for anything else. Earlier I tried to add PATH but once again it did not work.

Comment: @Nathan it's not a JDK, so you can't compile with it, and you should have no reason in 2020 to run a JRE for anything whatsoever, given that the concept 'JRE' has been deprecated for a decade now.

Comment: I was able to use JRE in the past on my Linux box but that was long time ago.

Comment: Use for what? If it's 'compiling', then, no, that's what JRE means: a JDK without compiler. If it's 'some app', sure, and you can use this JRE too, but that app is using an obsolete and unsupported deployment mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1

> What exactly am I trying to do? I am trying to compile Java programs using Command line. Android installed JDK for me so why not use it?

First of all, it is just the bundled JRE. Its is not JDK.

But, I was able to compile and run my `test.java` by adding two new entries in my environment variables.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

**NB:** I have never installed JDK before. I just used the JRE binaries present in `jre/bin/` present within Android Studio folder

See the attached image.

[image: CmdPromptProof.png]

I think you should recheck your environment variable or else try to get Android Studio latest release.